# Fourier Transform only defined in some interval

Tags: fourier-transform

$f(x)$ is defined over ($−\infty, \infty)$. fourier transfrom of $f(x)$ is $g(w)$ ≈ $1-w^2$ for small $w$ ($w<<1$) but $g(w)$ over full range of $w$ is not provided. Can we calculate the value of $$\int_{−\infty}^\infty x^2f(x) \,dx?$$

Comment: You're leaving something out - you must be given _something_ about $f$ that you're not telling us. Like $f\in L^1$ or $f\in L^2$ or something. ALso of course knowing just $g(w) ≈ 1-w^2$ cannot possiblly allow you to calculate _anything_ precisely. Or maybe it does, depending on exactly what you mean by $g(w)≈1-w^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think that's what the question is meant to be. It is a multiple choice question and has a following option - It is not possible to determine the value of this integral given the information provided

Comment: What does the ≈ mean, exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Not sure, but I assume it is same as =.

Comment: Well if you're not sure what the notation means of course you can't do the problem! You need to get the notation straight first. It should say  somewhere, wherever this came from. I suppose it _could_ be that ≈ is supposed to be the same as =, but that seems unlikely -  why wouldn't the author have just written =?

Answer (score 2):

Yes because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 f(x)dx = - \frac{d^2}{d \omega^2}g(\omega)|_{\omega = 0}$. If we know $g(\omega)$ for small positive $\omega$ then we also know its second derivative and can safely take its limit.

This will work provided that we can interchange the integral and the derivative.

Comment: But we don't know $g(w)$ for small $w$. Or maybe we do, depending on what the ≈ means...

Comment: I expect it to mean there are higher order terms, which would evaluate to zero here.